# How can I configure an external image loader in next.js properly?

Tags: next.js, imgix

I'm using next.js export to create a static html export which is hosted on google cloud storage.

I use this workaround in my next.js configuration.

```
images: {
 loader: 'imgix',
 path: 'https://noop/',
},
```

How do I need to configure an external loader e.g. imgix properly to work?

Answer (score 3):

#### Relative Path

```js
images: {
    deviceSizes: [320, 420, 768, 1024, 1200],
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "https://<account>.imgix.net/",
},
```

Then in your component,

```js
const imgSrc = "random.png";

<Image
     src={imgSrc} // <= https://<account>.imgix.net/random.png
     width={300}
     height={300}
     alt={alt}
   />
```

#### Absolute Path

```js
images: {
    deviceSizes: [320, 420, 768, 1024, 1200],
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "",
},
```

Then in your component,

```js
const imgSrc = "https://<imagesource-domain>/random.png";

<Image
     src={imgSrc} // <= https://<imagesource-domain>/random.png
     width={300}
     height={300}
     alt={alt}
   />
```

Comment: Ok, but this means random.png must be uploaded to imgix seperatly, correct? I always thought nextjs will optimize images at compile time.

Comment: Yes and no. If you want to use a cloud provider to optimize images instead of using the Next.js' built-in Image Optimization, you can configure the loader and path prefix. i.e imgix